# Create new object if it doesn't exist, else update

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having quite some trouble handling objects and storing them as JSON.

What I'm trying to do is next:

1. parse json file

```
var links = JSON.parse([{"user1":{"username":"user1","data":"164"}},{"user2":{"username":"user2","status":0}}]);
```

2. If user1 exists, update the whole object with new data, ELSE create new object

```
  var key     =  dater['username']; //dynamic username strings

  var ACCOUNT =  {
                    username: key,
                    data: value, 
                    status:1
                }

if(links.hasOwnProperty(key)){

   links[key] = ACCOUNT;
   links=JSON.stringify(links);

   fs.writeFile('status.json', links, err => {
       // error checking
       if(err) throw err;

       console.log('Exists.. updating.');
   });
}else{  // ELSE create new entry

       links.push({[key]: ACCOUNT});
       newData= JSON.stringify(links);

       fs.writeFile('status.json', newData, err => {
           // error checking
            if(err) throw err;

             console.log('New user.. creating');
       });

}
```

As you can probably tell, the above doesn't work as I'd want it to. I'm used with PHP arrays where I would simply do arrays with keys and directly update them without any 'if/else'

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a bit general, could you please specify what error you're getting, or if there's no error what is the unexpected behavior that's happening?

Comment: @RonB. , links.hasOwnProperty doesn't work because there are multiple objects, doing a for would probably work but I'd really not want to iterate through each json at each execution, searching for the exact key.

Comment: @RonB. I'd pretty much need something like this {key1:{}, key2.{}}.hasOwnProperty(key) -> which would therefore work without any 'for' involved. not sure if possible, that's why I'm here on stackoverflow. Is such format possible? Currently I have {key1:{}},{key2:{}}, which doesn't really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const key = dater['username']; //dynamic username strings

const account = {
    username: key,
    data: value,
    status: 1,
};

const matchedItem = links.find((i) => i[key]);

if (matchedItem) {
    matchedItem[key] = account;
} else {
    links.push({ [key]: account });
}

console.log('links:::', links);

fs.writeFile('status.json', JSON.stringify(links), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('New user.. creating');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your usage of `JSON.parse` is incorrect, because the purpose of it is to take a string in JSON format and parse it to a JS object (or any other entity encoded in it). Your passing to it an array, and because JS has very expected and intuitive behavior, it tries to convert it to a string which end up being `[Object object]`, which should result an error.

I assume it's just a typo and you forgot the "" before and after the array.

Second, `links` is an array. When you're using `hasOwnProperty` on this array, you're asking whether the array itself has this key, and not whether one of its members has.

There are 2 options:

**Either**

You can loop over the array with the `some` function and check whether one of the objects in the array has this key like so:

`const isUserAlreadyExists = links.some(userObj => userObj.hasOwnProperty(key))`

And use this as your condition

**Or**

Remodel your data so it's an object with the user names as keys, something like:

```
{
   user1: {username: "user1", data: whatever},
   user2: {username: "user2", data: whatever}
   ...
}
```

And then your current solution should work.
I would suggest the second solution since your data model seems a bit weird, maybe consider different data structure altogether.

To do that, your initial data will have to be an empty object (`const links = {}` or wherever you're getting it from)

And then you can just keep the part in your `if` clause and it should work

So your code should be something like:

```
  var key     =  dater['username']; //dynamic username strings

  var ACCOUNT =  {
                    username: key,
                    data: value, 
                    status:1
                }

   links[key] = ACCOUNT;
   links=JSON.stringify(links);

   fs.writeFile('status.json', links, err => {
       // error checking
       if(err) throw err;

       console.log('Exists.. updating.');
   });
```

This way you don't have to check if the `key` property exists in your object, because if it doesn't it will simply create it and if it does it will overwrite whatever's stored in there

Comment: Could you edit your answer with an example on how to remodel the data as specified by you above? That was kind of the whole purpose of my question. Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to keep your current data and you just want to restructure it, or can you delete it all, start from scratch and I'll show you how to handle additions?

Comment: I don't need to keep the current data. The data was populated in the ELSE part of my code.

Comment: I edited it, hope it's helpful. The main takeaway is that you can store your data in an object rather than an array of objects with one property and a nested object, it seems to suit your purpose better.

Comment: @RonB. why do you think that `links[key] = ACCOUNT` should work?  Please note that the `list` is not an object. It is an array of objects

Comment: @CyberEternal I know, that's why I said it should be converted to an object, just one line before that

Comment: Ah ok. I agree with you @RonB. Of course, it will be better to have a good structure of data instead of the current.